# how to set the position of a radio button group

Tags: java, android, position, radio-group

the default position of the radio group is the top left side of the screen, and I want it to be at the top right. i tried to use padding like so:
`radioGroup.setPadding(layout.getRight() - radioGroup.getWidth(), layout.getTop(), layout.getRight(), layout.getTop() + radioGroup.getHeight())`
but it won't change the radio gruop's position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RadioGroup parent is a RelativeLayout, just add the tags `android:layout_alignParentRight=true` and `android:layout_alignParentTop=true`.

Via code, check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html .
It's a matter of using `addRule()` for specifying both constraints in your `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` object, and then applying it to the RadioGroup.

If your RadioGroup parent is a LinearLayout, try setting the LinearLayout `android:gravity="top|right"`.

Similarly, via code, you can use `setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT)` in your `LinearLayout` object.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps a little bit more now!

Comment: it works great, but when I add a text that is related to a button, it comes of its right and pushes the button... any way I can set its position to be left of the button?

Comment: not sure, I haven't been able to do it myself using the default RadioButton.